# COR para directing? - Organic chemistry

Tags: organic-chemistry

Why does COCH3 become para-directing? I thought that COR was meta-directing. Is it because of the AlCl3, or is there another explanation?

[image: From a previous exam set]

Comment: COR is meta directing. NH2 however is o,p directing and the reaction you have drawn is the acylation of Ph-NH2

Answer (score 2):

Waylander says it all.  A carbonyl-bearing group is deactivating and meta directing when it is on the substrate ring.  But here the carbonyl-bearing group comes from the electrophile and instead, an amino group is attached to the ring.  The direction comes from the amino group, which is activating and ortho/para directing, and as with most such groups steric effects favor the para product.